# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null (Select2 dropdown)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[image that error occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBN3e.png)

When I try to apply the select2 method into my select box. After that, I tried to select the data from the drop down, but it will return error in the inspect element which is **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null**. Anyone know how to fix this error??

Code (javascript)

```
$(".oopt_" + product_id).append("<tr><td>" + name + "<span class='help'>(Optional)</span></td><td><select class='attname1_" + product_id + " getval_" + product_id + "" + index + "' style='width:193px'; id='" + value['attribute_id'] + "'></select></td></tr>");

//append the option value
$.each(value['options'], function(key1, value1) {

  if (value1 == textvalue) {
    $(".getval_" + product_id + "" + index + "").append($("<option selected='selected'></option>").attr("value", value1).text(value1));
  } else {
    $(".getval_" + product_id + "" + index + "").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value1).text(value1));
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#" + value['attribute_id']).select2();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this

```
$(".getval_" + product_id + "" + index + "")
```

does not return a DOM element.